# How to speed up List access in JPA

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa

In my mapper class, I always have to retrieve a list of departments from my company entity :

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  public List<CompanyDepartments> getDepartments()
  {
    return departments; //java.util.List variable. 
  }
```

There are a couple thousand departments(about 2000+). I am trying to reduce the time taken to fetch company data and want to begin with the departments which are going to be fairly static in nature.

**Option 1 :** I can always have a private method in the mapper which populates a cache on the first load and return from the cache all the time.
 
But is there anything more simpler? I am probably not the first one to face this and wanted to know how I could approach this. Is there a known annotation that can be used. Like a @Singleton annotation on the variable in the entity ? (there is no such annotation obviously). What is the simplest way to make this list a singleton.

Just a typical spring mvc 3 application using spring data jpa for db interaction.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this link that solves the n +1 query problem ... 
[How can i resolve the N+1 Selects problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593029/how-can-i-resolve-the-n1-selects-problem)

Moreover you could put a cache (lvl 2) on your search service,
if the data does not change during the life cycle of the application.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

Another approach is to add to indexes on the db.

I hope I've given you all the answers about your question.

Answer (score 1):

What you're experiencing is part of the "object-relational impedance mismatch". One solution would be  to extend your object model so that you can use a **left join fetch** to load multiple companies including their departments using only one SQL statement.

The problem using this technique is that you can populate only one list at a time. Although it's nice & easy to define many sub-lists in the world of objects, it's hard to load all these lists at the same time (and therefor efficiently) from a relational database. However it *can* be done on Oracle using object- or XMLType queries.

The straight-forward way to get such data out of a RDBMS is by writing custom queries that match exactly the task at hand and provide only the data that is actually needed. **Therefor you'd need not only one company class, but many - one for each task.** - you'd actually do inheritance instead of attribution

BTW, that is why ORM is still considered the [Vietnam of Computer science](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404083/is-orm-still-the-vietnam-of-computer-science) - easy to get started, but hard to succeed with.